# Accessing entire MEAN application remotely within a LAN?(without deploying on cloud)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have a MEAN application build running on my own personal system. My node server running at port 8000 and angular application at 4200. When it tries to access the application remotely from another machine in my LAN I couldn't load data from database to display it on the system (remote one).

The application running on my system: [image: running at localhost:4200]

The application running on the remote system: [image: running at IP of my system:4200]

No data is displayed on the remote machine.

How could I solve this?

Comment: without source code hard to tell, do you use relative urls?

Comment: https://github.com/gurucharanD/movieshub this is my github repo you can find the  soure code of my entire application here @Peter

Comment: in https://github.com/gurucharanD/movieshub/blob/master/movies-hub/client/src/app/movie.service.ts
you hard coded local host `this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/movieslist')` 
thats why